# How do I search only when user press enter button?

Tags: javascript, dom-events

I am learning react.
I have an input component.

```html
<InputText
  isdisabled={false}                                      
  placeholder="Type something and press enter to search..."
  type="text"
  name="search-table"                    
  onChange={(e) => handleSearch(e)}                    
/>
```

I have a `handleSearch` function, I want to search only when user hit enter key.

```js
const handleSearch = (e) => {
  console.log(e.keyCode, e.keyCode, e.which); // undefined
  if(e.key === 'Enter' || e.keyCode === 13) {
    // API CALL
  }
}
```

But when I print `console.log(e.keyCode, e.keyCode, e.which);` It is returning `undefined` because it is now **[deprecated](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/keyCode)**.

So how can I achieve my goal ?

Comment: wrap the input element on form and add a button and then use the onSubmit;

Comment: any other solution ?

Comment: Use [code](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/code) as recommended on the deprecated attribute page? You also might want use the keypress event instead of change.

Comment: you can pick the element using ref and then add a custom event listener to it

Comment: If you want to perform the search when user hits enter, then you shouldn't be listening to the `change` event but the `keypress` event.

Comment: got I am now using `keypress`

Answer (score 0):

```
<InputText
isdisabled={false}                                      
placeholder="Type something and press enter to search..."
type="text"
name="search-table"
onkeypress={(e) => handleSearch(e)}     
onChange={(e) => handleSearch(e)}>
```

OnKeyPress return the key what key you have entered and check condition in your function Body

```
const handleSearch = (e) => {

  if (e.key === 'Enter' || e.keyCode === 13){
    // API CALL
    }}
```